# Image "Upload" to Canvas Object With JQuery - Not Saving on Server

Tags: jquery, html, file-upload, canvas, html5-canvas

I was just curious if, on a purely html/jquery page, it is possible to have the user "upload" an image but where the image data goes right to a canvas object on the page, and is not saved to the server in any way.  I am trying to avoid the use of php or any server side language and am hoping this can be done.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you post some code so that we can look to it where the problem really is?And are you using any upload control?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, with HTML5's File API images can be read to base 64 (<-most commonly used) directly from the users filesystem, and then be put right into a canvas without storing anything to the server or using php at all.

You will have to search around a little, as this is fairly new stuff, but there is a pretty good tutorial on the [Mozilla Dev pages.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications)

Just did something similar for a site I was working on, and the FileReader, drag and drop, and most other html5 functions worked great on all modern browsers (that of course excludes IE), but if that's a problem you could have a php backup or something.

Comment: Excellent stuff; I am looking into it now.  I will get back shortly and checkmark the question if all goes well.

Comment: This appears to work in only Firefox; is there a cross browswer solution (If only IE doesn't work I can live with that).  You can email me from my account info if its easy to chat offline; thanks!

Comment: Firefox and Chrome have full support for the filereader and File API, Opera supports the File API from version 11 and up, but does not have support for drag and drop or object url's, Safari 6 and up supports the File API, that's basically all the modern browser. IE has support for drag and drop and some similar functions thru DirectX since IE6 or something, and as of today IE9 has no support for any of this, other than thru the previously mentioned DirectX stuff that I don't really know that much about.